# Find not matching a grep, after results

Tags: find

Hopefully this is a simple one, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to work out why this command isn't finding any results:

```
find . -iname '*.cgi' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' -o -iname '*.php' -exec grep -l 'community.cgi' {} +
```

If I simplify it and just do:

```
find . -iname '*.cgi' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' -o -iname '*.php'
```

Then I get the list of files I'm expecting. For some reason the `-exec` part doesn't seem to be what I'm expecting. If I just run a basic grep on ALL files, I get the list of files as well:

```
grep -l 'community.cgi' .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical-and binds tighter than logical-or.  Try:

```
find . \( -iname '*.cgi' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' -o -iname '*.php' \) -exec grep -l 'community.cgi' {} +
```

Here, parens (which have to be escaped to pass through the shell) are used to bind the `-iname` tests together so that `-exec` runs if any one of those tests is true.